# Proving a theorem about matrix derivations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Ok, so Im doing some research and I have to understand the following theorem. The theorem states:  Let $h$ be a derivation on $Tn(R)$ with $h(e_{ij})=0,\,\, 1\le i \le j \le n$. Then $h=\bar\delta$ for some derivation $\delta$ on $R$.

Ok, so what I understand so far is this, that if h is a derivation, that means that it must satisfy two things:

1.)For every $r,s \in R$ show $\delta(r+s)=\delta(r)+\delta(s)$

2.)For every $r,s \in R$ show $(rs)'=rs'+r's$

Proving 1.) $\delta(r+s)$$=(r+s)'=r'+s'=\delta(r)+\delta(s)$
I had some trouble proving two, which I know is just the product rule but we cannot assume that here, we have to prove it using other methods and Im not sure how. 
$Tn(R)$ is the set of all upper triangular matrices and that $h(e_{ij})=0$ means that when we take the derivative of $e_{ij}$ we get 0.Then $h=\bar\delta$, which im assuming is the conjugate??? Im not sure here. this is all I have so far on this, any help would be appreciated. For a full report of the research paper this comes from you can go herehttp://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959390141A

Comment: I downloaded the paper from the link you gave and skimmed through it. I don't see where they make the claim from your question. Are you talking about lemma 2 at the bottom of page 265, where we have an $h$ with the properties from your question and want to show that $h(rI) = \delta(r)I?$

Comment: @jflipp, the theorem i previously gave stems from that, it is not specifically stated in the paper but i was asked to understand the theorem based on the paper.

Comment: Here are some remarks, just to make sure we're talking about the same things. First, according to the paper, $R$ is a ring with unit. Then $T_n(R)$ also is a ring with unit. Second, a derivation on any ring $S$ is by definition a map $\delta:S\rightarrow S$ that satisfies $\forall x,y \in S: \delta(x+y) = \delta(x) + \delta(y)$ and $\forall x,y \in S: \delta(xy) = \delta(x)y + x\delta(y)$. That's exactly as you stated in your question. In particular, we can have $S = R$ or $S = T_n(R)$.

Comment: [continued] Third, in the introduction of the paper, they construct from a given derivation $\delta$ of $R$ a derivation $\overline\delta$ of $T_n(R)$. I don' reproduce the definition of $\overline\delta$ here. You should check (and I think that's not so difficult) that $\overline\delta$ is indeed a derivation of $T_n(R).$ Now we come to your research task. You are given a derivation $h$ of $T_n(R)$ with the additional property $\forall 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n: h(e_{ij}) = 0.$ Note that you don't have to prove that $h$ is a derivation. That's given.

Comment: [continued] Your task is to find a derivation $\delta$ of $R$ such that the given $h$ with the given properties is equal to $\overline\delta$ where $\overline\delta$ is constructed from $\delta$ as mentioned in my third point above. The bar in $\overline\delta$ has absolutely nothing to do with conjugation. So much for your task. Right now, my guess is that this can be carried out by using some techniques from the paper.

Comment: @jflipp, thank you for your remarks, I have taken what you you have said under consideration. Though I believe I understand the first statement in the theorem, Im still not sure how to venture into working out the $h=\bar\delta$ part of theorem. I will continue to read futher.

Comment: I think I am mainly having problems understand what $\bar\delta$ means. I know that when applied to a function, its telling me to take the derivative of each element in the function, such as $\bar\delta(e_{ij})=[\delta(e_{ij})]$